# Unable to run packages installed using npm on VM provisioned by Chef

Tags: node.js, chef-infra, npm-install, chef-recipe

I provisioned my VM on AWS using Chef and installed NodeJS using the NodeJS recipe (https://github.com/redguide/nodejs). When I do a global npm install of any package, I am not able to run that package using command line. Attached the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: You will have to add the `/usr/local/nodejs-binary-6.3.0/bin/` to your path I guess

Comment: If I do that it works.

Comment: Usually, I run the package binaries using absolute path..

Comment: It makes sure it doesn't pollute your path

Answer (score 0):

My `poise-javascript` cookbook has `node_package` and `javascript_execute` resources to take care of all the required path munging for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1)add the `/usr/local/nodejs-binary-6.3.0/bin/` to `PATH` variable.

Or

2)Run `/usr/local/nodejs-binary-6.3.0/bin/http-server`.

The npm package binaries are not added to path by default. I would prefer option 2 to keep the path `unpolluted`